# Equivalence of algebraic and geometric statements of Sylvester's Law of Inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that Sylvester's Law tells us that the number of positive (resp. negative, null) eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix is invariant under diagonalization.

I also believe that this can be alternately formulated as the dimension of the maximal positive-definite (resp. negative definite) subspaces being invariant.

I belive I understand each statement, but how can I show that these are equivalent? I believe I'm missing a crucial detail concerning the relationship between eigenvalues and the dimension of subspaces.

I suppose this question could be: how can I prove that the number of positive eigenvalues of a space is equal to the dimension of a maximal positive-definite subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have diagonalized the real symmetric matrix $A = U D U^\top$
with an orthogonal matrix $U$.
The span of the columns of $U$ that are the eigenvectors corresponding to positive eigenvalues will be the maximal positive-definite subspace, which thus will have dimension equal to the number of positive eigenvalues.